# Splitting implicit GNU make rule

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following implicit rule:

```
CFLAGS=-I../tcp/ -I../libip_udp/ -g -Wall                                        
LDLIBS=framework.o ../tcp/libtcp.a ../libip_udp/libip.a                          

%.run : %.c $(LDLIBS)                                                            
        $(CC) $< $(LDLIBS) -o $@ $(CFLAGS)                                       
        ./$@
```

If I run `make foo.run` it will compile foo.c and execute foo.run. However, running `make foo.run` a second time will not do anything. How can I split the implicit rule such that it compiles when needed, but runs always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
CFLAGS=-I../tcp/ -I../libip_udp/ -g -Wall
LDLIBS=framework.o ../tcp/libtcp.a ../libip_udp/libip.a

.SECONDARY:

%.run : %.c $(LDLIBS)
        $(CC) $< $(LDLIBS) -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

exec.%: %
        ./$<
```

Now just run it

```
make exec.foo.run
```